# simple 2d collision in monogame (using xna pipeline)

Tags: c#, collision, detection, monogame

I am just starting to learn monogame and I am using the XNA pipeline (search RBWhitiker) to create a 2d platformer, however I have become stuck when trying to get my player to jump on a platform.

My player can run past the platform and jump, which is desired.

The problem is that when the player comes to jump on the platform, he sort of "locks" into the last y position he was it at when he crossed into the same x-coordinates of the platform, and therefore just floats in mid air above the platform.

The other issue is that the player cannot jump when they are on the platform either.

Hope this doesn't sound too confusing, but any help would be appreciated!

Player.cs - code for jumping

```
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) && isJumping == false)
        {
            position.Y -= 30;
            velocity.Y = -7f;
            isJumping = true;
            isOnFloor = false;
        }

        if (isJumping == true)
        {
            velocity.Y += 0.4f;
        }

        if (position.Y >= 480)
        {
            isJumping = false;
            isOnFloor = true;
        }

        if (position.Y < 480)
        {
            isOnFloor = false; 
        }

        if (isJumping == false)
        {
            velocity.Y = 0f;
        }
```

Game.cs - HandleCollisions Function, which is called in Update()

```
    private void HandleCollisions()
    {
        if (myPlayer.boundingBox.Intersects(myPlatform.boundingBox))
        {
            myPlayer.velocity.Y = 0f;
            myPlayer.isOnFloor = false;
        }
    }
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Qks0VNpHCQ

Here is a video to better illustrate my problem. 
A couple of points:

- I know, the images are from broforce, this is just a sample sprite and will be changed later
- at the end where the character remains still floating above the platform, I am pressing jump multiple times, but the player does not jump

Comment: Can you tell me what the player position.Y is when he's stuck?

Comment: It entirely depends on what height you are at when you attempt to jump on the platform, which is anywhere between 430 and the floor (480). If it helps, I could link a video to properly describe what is happening?

Comment: You could if you'd like.  I just really would want to know the exact location of the player (X and Y values) when the floating and inability to jump is occurring so that I can step through the logic.  You could set a breakpoint or just continuously print the values as the game is running.

Comment: I don't think it's enough to just know if the bounding box's intersect. You'll also need to calculate how far away the box's are from each other and perhaps which side the player is on. Then you'll need to calculate where the player should be after the collision. As you've already experienced, this kind of code can get pretty difficult to debug. Adding some logging should help. Also, consider moving some of the code in Player.cs to HandleCollisions. Most of this code is probably not the concern of the player and moving it out will make it easier to reason about imho.

Comment: I've added a video to better illustrate the problem I'm having, many thanks for your replies.

Comment: Could you add the code for the bounding boxes? And why do you have two variables for basically the same thing? (isonfloor and isjumping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: turns out that it was no the collision that was the problem, but what occured inside the if-statements :)